why does using location interface cause an error
I have a function using location
ts file

  isHomePage() {
    return location.pathname == '/';
  }

css file
<a routerLink="/" [ngClass]="{'current-active':isHomePage()}" class="nav-link " aria-current="page">Home</a>

It is working at browser but i have an error at Angular cli
ERROR ReferenceError: location is not defined
My tsconfig.json file

{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}



Please share your tsconfig.json

What is location expected to hold? If you're trying to update window.location.pathname, then that's readonly.

I have just shared tsconfig.json

maybe you should use this one https://angular.dev/api/common/Location?tab=api and import { Location } from '@angular/common'; constructor(private location: Location)

Yes it works but it works with isCurrentPathEqualTo or other similar properties not with pathname i think its because angular location and js location difference

Well i couldn't fix location is not defined error but instead of that i used router service, code below
    export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router)
  {

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
   
  }
  isHomePage(): boolean {

    return this.router.url === '/';
  }

}

